# Converting seconds to HH:MM:SS using Prometheus & Grafana

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to show system uptime as DD-HH-MM-SS format, doing it using common code wouldn't be an issue but I'm doing it using Prometheus (PromQL) and Grafana only, here's the PromQL query:

`time()-process_start_time_seconds{instance="INSTANCE",job="JOB"}`

I achieved the basic output I wanted, it shows me the process life time. The output for the query above gives me time in seconds (for instance **68003**) and converts it to bigger time units (minutes, hours etc.), but in its decimal form:

[image: decimal uptime]

The **89** after the decimal point refers to 89% of an hour,about 53 minutes.
That's not a really "intuitive" way to show time, I would have liked it to display a normal DD:HH:MM:SS presentation of that time like the following screenshot from a simple online tool that converts seconds to time:

[image: regular uptime]

Is there away to achieve it using only PromQL and Grafana configuration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using "Unit" drop-down in the visualization section and select your unit as duration with the hh:mm:ss format, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Almost 3 years later but I have to say "I love it".